# How to generate random IPv4 number for a given country?

Tags: algorithm, ip-address, ipv4

Having IPv4 address ranges for a given country, how would one generate random address? For example, a single current set of ranges (one of many) for Singapore is:

```
+----------+----------+--------------+
| ip_from  | ip_to    | country_code |
+----------+----------+--------------+
| 18925568 | 18926079 | SG           |
+----------+----------+--------------+
```

*[source: lite.ip2location.com](https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country)*

[FAQ(3)](https://lite.ip2location.com/faqs) explains that

```
IP_Number = 16777216*w + 65536*x + 256*y + z
```

where

```
IP_Address = w.x.y.z
```

`IP_Number` standing either for `ip_from` or `ip_to`. For the Singapore range presented above, it gives me:

```
16777216*w + 65536*x + 256*y + z >= 18925568; // from
16777216*w + 65536*x + 256*y + z <= 18926079; // to
```

How can I generate random `w`, `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: Generate a random number in the range, then repeatedly div/mod by 256.

Comment: div/mod by 256 repeatedly and then validate ip (should not end to 0 or 255).

Comment: IP addresses are not allocated per country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a testable implementation (in JavaScript since that can be run directly here) and a little bit of a description.

First you need to generate random number from the specified range. If you have a function (let's call it `random`) that generates random real numbers between 0 and 0.999... `[0,1)` then you can do this.

```
num = (random() * (end - start + 1)) + start
```

Then you need to use `mod 256` 4 times to split the number into 4 parts and also use `div 256` 3 times on the given number (the fourth `div` operation would be unnecessary but if we are doing it in loop then we can just keep it there for the sake of simplicity as it doesn't change a thing).

```
(% - modulo, // - div)

first = num % 256
num = num // 256

second = num % 256
num = num // 256

third = num % 256
num = num // 256

fourth = num % 256
```

You can then push them into an array `[fourth, third, second, first]` (note the **order** here) and do some validation - some addresses are reserved for private internets so if you happen to generate one of them, just throw it away and generate a new one (you can either loop or recurse here till you generate a valid one).

Ip addresses in these ranges are reserved according to RFC 1918:

```
10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

And here is the implementation.

```js
const start = 18925568;
const end = 18926079;

function _generateRandomIp(start, end) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1)) + start;

  const ip = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ip.push(r % 256);
    r = Math.floor(r / 256);
  }

  return ip.reverse(); // put the results mod/div into correct order
}

function generateRandomIp(start, end) {
  let ip = _generateRandomIp(start, end);
  let valid = true;

  // ip can't be of format 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
  if (ip[0] === 10) { valid = false; }

  // ip can't be of format 172.16.xxx.xxx
  if (ip[0] === 172 && ip[1] === 16) { valid = false; }

  // ip can't be of format 192.168.xxx.xxx
  if (ip[0] === 192 && ip[1] === 168) { valid = false; }

  if (valid === true) {
    return ip.join('.'); // convert ip to string format
  } else {
    return generateRandomIp(start, end); // try again
  }
}

const ip = generateRandomIp(start, end);
console.log(ip);
```

The above snippet will generate a random ip address in that range each time you run it.

And here is the test case from the page that you have mentioned which says that number `3401190660` should be converted into `202.186.13.4`, so let's just switch that randomly generated number for this one and try it.

```js
const start = 18925568;
const end = 18926079;

function _generateRandomIp(start, end) {
  let r = 3401190660; // here is that specific number

  const ip = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ip.push(r % 256);
    r = Math.floor(r / 256);
  }

  return ip.reverse(); // put the results mod/div into correct order
}

function generateRandomIp(start, end) {
  let ip = _generateRandomIp(start, end);
  let valid = true;

  // ip can't be of format 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
  if (ip[0] === 10) { valid = false; }

  // ip can't be of format 172.16.xxx.xxx
  if (ip[0] === 172 && ip[1] === 16) { valid = false; }

  // ip can't be of format 192.168.xxx.xxx
  if (ip[0] === 192 && ip[1] === 168) { valid = false; }

  if (valid === true) {
    return ip.join('.'); // convert ip to string format
  } else {
    return generateRandomIp(start, end); // try again
  }
}

const ip = generateRandomIp(start, end);
console.log(ip);
```

And as we can see, this algorithm produced the correct result.